# How to lock slot interaction to armor stands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried all i could possibly think off , there is a tag for locking slots but it does not work, i tried locking all slots, only weapon slots but it wont work, as soon as i click the armor stand i pick up the items.
Is it due to my op or game mode?

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{},{id:"iron_sword",Count:1b}],DisabledSlots:65793,Pose:{LeftArm:[271f,0f,271f]}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your commmands avoid replacing and placing items in the armorstand inventory (Removing shouldn't work but it does for some odd reason). All you should change is the Disable slot number to 2039583

[This link](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/#!42082) sends you to a great armorstand generator.

Edit2:

I got this one working for some odd reason.

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",Count:1b},{}],Pose:{Body:[0f,0f,0f],LeftArm:[0f,0f,0f],RightArm:[271f,0f,271f],LeftLeg:[0f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[0f,0f,0f],Head:[0f,0f,0f]},DisabledSlots:2039583}
```

Comment: thank you i´ll test it out and see if it works

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind telling me what are you working on or whenever it is finished letting me know? I'm kinda curious...

Comment: im creating a table rpg map and im building a city, using this specific armor stand to decorate a anvil in the blacksmith house

Comment: and i tested out the command, it still let´s you pick the iron sword

Comment: I got it working. Not sure why the other one didn't work.

Comment: do you want to enter my server?

Comment: cus i copy and paste your command and it did not work

Comment: Did you copy the new one I edited (In the answer)? If it doesn't work, i'm not sure what is happening. Sorry, can't get in right now.

Comment: idk what happened but now it worked

Comment: thank you, if you want to look at what i am doing you´re welcome at my server :)