# How can I keep players from taking the armor from armor stands for minecraft bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a Bedrock server, and there is a bunch of armor stand statues, but all the players will break them. How do I stop them from taking the armor?

Comment: Related, in Java edition: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359666/how-to-lock-slot-interaction-to-armor-stands

Comment: I don't think it's possible in BE.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I have found a way.
You need to turn on experimental gameplay, and use the command:

`/give @s structure_void`

It will give you a block similar to a barrier block, but you can walk through it and you can't change armor stands unless the player's position is at the same position of the stands' feet. The best workaround is to put a barrier or another block where the stand's feet are.

I got this answer from the reddit user u/MisledWater079

Answer (score 0):

A much easier fix is to simply use Worldedit, a very very useful plugin that I'm sure you have already.

Before creating the armour stand place 2 blocks where it is going to be, highlight those blocks using the wand (left click one block, right click the other) then place down the armour stand and type "//set barrier"

This will set the blocks that the armour stand is in to a transparent block that cannot be broken.

Hope this helps!